# Using VBA to Create Word Label Sheets, Getting Extra Unwanted Document

Tags: ms-access, ms-word, vba

I am trying to use VBA to create a label form in Word using data provided from Access. This VBA code works:

```
Dim appwd As Object
Dim oDoc As Object

Set appwd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
With appwd
    .Documents.Add
    Set oDoc = .MailingLabel.CreateNewDocumentByID(LabelID:="1359804671")
    .Visible = True
    .Activate
End With

oDoc.Activate

'Remaining code that creates labels
```

However, it creates and opens the blank Document1 as well as the Labels2 document I want. How do I prevent it from creating the unwanted Document1, or at the very least close that document again without saving it?

If I comment out the `.Documents.Add`, then I get

> Run-time error '4605':
>
> This method or property is not available because a document window is not active.

Comment: .Documents.Add , seems to be creating a new blank document.  Have you tried removing that code?

Comment: Well, `.Documents.Add` tends to add new documents. Provide the full code so we can actually correct it (we don't have any code opening your document)

Comment: What if you get your MailingLabel object from appwd instead of oDoc?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/mailinglabel-object-word says you can do that.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth That is the full code with the exception of Dim, which I just edited in. That code will create the document, the rest of the remaining code just adds label stuff. That all works and is not relevant to this question.

Comment: Note that I've optimized my answer a bit, does it still work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `.MailingLabel` object requires a document to be open, so the best alternative is to just close that document as soon as you create your desired one:

```
Dim appwd As Object
Dim oDoc As Object
Set appwd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
With appwd
    .Documents.Add
    Set oDoc = .MailingLabel.CreateNewDocumentByID(LabelID:="1359804671")
    .Documents(1).Close SaveChanges:=0 'wdDoNotSaveChanges, close the first document
    .Visible = True
    .Activate
End With

oDoc.Activate
```